# Why offline regulator output diodes have a high voltage rating?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply

I am currently having a look at AC to DC offline buck regulators - regulators which convert AC mains voltage to smaller DC, without any isolation transformers. Two examples are AP3917 from Diodes Semi, and FSL336 from ON Semi. Here is an example application circuit:
[image]

Both of these IC's have [design spreadsheets](https://www.onsemi.com/support/design-resources/tools?rpn=FSL336LR) to help with the calculations. However they both calculate the minimum reverse voltage ratings of output freewheeling diodes as 500'ish Volts. What is the reason, since the output should be 24V? I was planning to use a 40V Schottky Diode for my output for better efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left node of the inductor where the freewheeling diode connects is not the low voltage output. When the high side switch closes it connects that node to the full voltage of the input which the diode must block.